Unable to build next.js project for electron
I'm working on a project which involves next.js, electron (for packaging) and python (for backend).
This is my first project in this domain, so I'm encountering some error while building the project.
I've used electro's ipc within my source code and it is working fine when I run it on dev mode-> it starts the process on localhost:3000 and then spins up electron window, and then utilizes the ipc to generate response from the python backend like:
main.js:
const { app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain } = require('electron');
const path = require('path');
const { spawn } = require('child_process');

async function createWindow() {
  const isDev = (await import('electron-is-dev')).default;
  const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    title: "chatbot",
    width: 1280,
    height: 720,
    webPreferences: {
      preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js'),
      contextIsolation: true,
      enableRemoteModule: true,
      nodeIntegration: false,
    }
  });
  var index_path = `file://${path.join(__dirname, '../out/index.html')}`
  // mainWindow.setMenu(null);
  mainWindow.loadURL(
    isDev
    ? 'http://localhost:3000'
    : index_path
  ); 
}

app.whenReady().then(() => {
  createWindow();
  console.log("A new window has been created!");

  ipcMain.on('sendMessage', (event, message) => {
    console.log("Hi, a message has been received");
    const python = spawn('python', [path.join(__dirname, 'script.py'), message]);

    python.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
      console.log("Hey, a new message has been received from python!");
      const result = JSON.parse(data);
      event.reply('reply', result.response); 
    });

    python.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
      console.error(`Error from Python script: ${data}`);
      // Send an error message back to the renderer
      event.reply('reply', 'An error occurred while processing your request.'); 
    });
  });

  app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
    if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
      app.quit();
    }
  });

  app.on('activate', () => {
    if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
      createWindow();
    }
  });
});

When I'm trying to build it after making a static build of next source code, I'm getting a source code, but it has paths which are not recognized by the index.html, and I've to manually modify them by adding a '.' before all the paths in the exported file, then only it is loading the css and JS part, but still not the electron thing.
This is the index.html file:
before
and I've to make:
after
This is made manually by me by adding a ".", only then the CSS is rendered, but still nothing related to electron is loaded and Whenever I'm sending a message, no response is returned.
This is my directory structure.
├── next-env.d.ts
├── next.config.mjs
├── electron
│   ├── preload.js
│   ├── script.py
│   └── main.js
├── tsconfig.json
├── .eslintrc.json
├── src
│   ├── components
│   │   ├── ui
│   │   │   ├── input.tsx
│   │   │   ├── button.tsx
│   │   │   └── avatar.tsx
│   │   └── component
│   │       ├── global.d.ts
│   │       └── chatbot.tsx
│   ├── app
│   │   ├── page.tsx
│   │   ├── favicon.ico
│   │   ├── globals.css
│   │   └── layout.tsx
│   ├── favicon.ico
│   └── lib
│       └── utils.ts
├── package.json
├── postcss.config.mjs
├── README.md
├── .gitignore
├── favicon.ico
├── package-lock.json
├── public
│   ├── next.svg
│   ├── vercel.svg
│   └── placeholder-user.jpg
├── tailwind.config.ts
└── components.json

I know it's quite ill-structured and not up to the mark, but still, I'm not able to diagnose the issue and why is this path problem occurring and I'm not getting a good build. Even I'm, able to make the electron distributable app, but it's the same as loading the static generated index.html file, so it doesn't work! But it works just fine when ran in dev mode.
These are my scripts:
  "scripts": {
    "electron:start": "npm run start-app",
    "electron:build": "npm run build && electron-builder",
    "electron:builder": "electron-builder",
    "dev": "next dev",
    "start-app": "cross-env BROWSER=none concurrently \"npm run dev\" \"npm run start-electron\"",
    "start-electron": "wait-on http://localhost:3000 &&  electron .",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint",
    "export": "next export",
    "serve": "serve out"
  }

Here, npm run electron:start works fine, but not the npm run electron-build
my build configuration:
"build": {
    "extends": null,
    "appId": "com.vw_chatbot..test",
    "files": [
      "dist/**/*",
      "out/**/*",
      "electron/**/*",
      "node_modules/**/*",
      "package.json"
    ],
    "directories": {
      "buildResources": "assets"
    },
    "extraMetadata":{
      "main": "electron/main.js"
    },
    "win":{
      "target": "nsis",
      "icon": "favicon.ico",
      "sign": null
    }
  }

I tried modifying the next.config.mjs file but still no success.
I also tried to find out similar chatbots that have been built using react + electron + python, but was not able to find one and even the one I was able to find was too old and that too was not building.
I used  this article for reference:
https://medium.com/heuristics/electron-react-python-part-1-introduction-b228ccf8e889
